# How do you access custom Follow-Up flag values ("Flag to...") in Outlook 2016?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm trying to work out how to access this custom Follow-up flag text in a list view, but cannot seem to find what I need in the available display fields.

---

Here's what I'm doing to flag a message to read later...

1. Add a custom flag

[image: 1. Add a custom flag]

2. Populate "Flag to" text

[image: 2. Populate "Flag to" text]

3. Mail now showing as flagged

[image]

4. **The Tasks list only shows basic flag status information**

[image]

---

I would like to access the "Flag to" field for filtering/grouping purposes, but I cannot find it in the field chooser menu...

[image]

---

Is it possible to access this value to create views?
If so, how?

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The field is called **Follow Up Flag**

Right click on Search Folder and select New Search Folder...

[image]

In Advanced tab > All Mail fields > Follow Up Flag:

[image]

Condition dropdown should be **is not empty**

Click OK

[image]

Now, you just need to Group By the field **Follow Up Flag**

You can see in my screenshot, I have four different groups. The default is **Follow Up**, but as you know, you can have other Follow Up flags.

[image]

One caveat: The Follow Up Flag is tied to the individual e-mails and not part of Tasks. This means that your Tasks, even if flagged, will not appear in this custom search.

Comment: Ta very much!  It makes perfect sense that this is all part of the mail item - I was distracted by the appearance of the item in the "Tasks" view.